# Find the value of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big( 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \Big) \cdots \Big(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}} \Big)$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big( 1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} \Big) \cdots  \Big(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}}  \Big)$$

**Attempt:**

Let $y = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big( 1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} \Big) \cdots  \Big(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}}  \Big)$

$\ln y = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln \Big( 1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} \Big)+ \cdots  + \ln \Big(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}}  \Big)$

I am not able to move ahead really from here. Could someone give me an hint on how to move forward with this problem.

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Comment: Same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795186/how-do-i-evaluate-prod-r-1-infty-left-1-frac1-sqrt-r1-right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the factors are positive, but bounded by the last one. Thus, for all $n$ the product is between $0$ and $(1-1/\sqrt{n+1})^n$. What happens with that expression as $n\to+\infty$?

Comment: The limit tends to $0$.

Comment: That is indeed correct.

Comment: The limit is $0$, or the sequence tends to $0$.

Comment: @GEdgar, that is indeed correct. (I agree with anyone commenting this answer.)